# Does the regular value theorem give an equivalent definition of manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, manifolds, definition

One has that the inverse image of a regular value is a manifold by applying the implicit function theorem, see e.g. [here](https://unapologetic.wordpress.com/2011/04/21/regular-and-critical-points/).

My question is the following: does the converse hold? I.e., can every manifold (theoretically) be written as the inverse image of a regular value?

I thought I remembered reading this somewhere but now I can't find it. Anyway I was wondering in particular if this result gives an alternative/equivalent definition for manifold which is less intuitive but might be easier to verify in some cases, e.g. spheres.

On the other hand I am not sure how such a weak condition could possibly guarantee that the resulting space is both Hausdorff and second countable, so I am somewhat skeptical that this could actually be true.

To be clear, a reference will suffice for an answer -- this is a dumb question and I don't want to waste too much of anyone's time with it.

Comment: You should probably mention, that you’re talking about submanifolds of $ℝ^n$. For abstract manifolds it would be trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comment: the inverse image of any point under a smooth map $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ (I assume this is the setting you're working in because you don't want to presuppose a notion of manifold) is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$, so automatically both Hausdorff and second countable. The hard part of the regular value theorem is how to get that the subspace is locally Euclidean, and that's where you need a regular value.

Answer: no. Manifolds that arise in this way must also admit [stable framings](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/framed+manifold), which means in particular that their stable [characteristic classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_class) must vanish. The simplest example of a manifold not admitting a stable framing is $\mathbb{RP}^2$, because its first Stiefel-Whitney class $w_1$ doesn't vanish; the simplest orientable example is $\mathbb{CP}^2$, because its first Pontryagin class $p_1$ (or, if you prefer, its second Stiefel-Whitney class $w_2$) doesn't vanish.

Comment: Dumb question then: this means that having a stable framing is different from being parallelizable, right? Since only the 0,1,3,7-spheres are parallelizable but any $n$-sphere is the inverse image of the regular value $1$ under $|| \cdot ||^2_{n+1}$, right? I.e. using the terminology of the linked nLab article, a trivialization not of the tangent bundle itself (which would correspond to a parallelizable manifold I think), but of the stable normal bundle? E.g. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_normal_bundle or in

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/231426/do-vanishing-characteristic-classes-of-the-tangent-bundle-imply-a-manifold-is-st -- and is Hatcher's "Vector Bundles and K-Theory" a good reference for this? I remember reading about parallelizability and tangent bundles in Lee's "Introduction to Smooth Manifolds" and Stiefel manifolds and fundamental classes (which are probably not the same thing or even related to stable characteristic classes or Stiefel-Whitney classes) in Bredon's "Topology and Geometry" -- I'm not quite certain what a good reference for stable framings and characteristic classes is

Comment: @William: "parallelizable" and "frameable" mean the same thing (the tangent bundle is trivializable), and so do "stably parallelizable" and "stably frameable" (the stable tangent bundle, or equivalently the stable normal bundle, is trivializable). I don't know a good reference; people recommend Milnor and Stasheff for characteristic classes, but honestly most of what I know about characteristic classes I learned by trying to write this blog post: https://qchu.wordpress.com/2014/06/16/hypersurfaces-4-manifolds-and-characteristic-classes/